# Error for RSS feed

Tags: rss

I used [this example](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/any-working-rss-feed-examples-out-there) to create an RSS feed in Craft, saved it as “rss.html”, uploaded it into the “craft/templates” directory, and created a custom route rss => templates/rss.

However, when I load our website to http://www.progress.org/rss I get the following error: “error on line 13 at column 9: Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 0 and head”

Any help is appreciated... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the source of the RSS page you're linked to, you'll see the underlying error causing your feed to mess up:

```
Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "pageDescription".
```

You didn't share your template code, but most like likely you're doing an `entry.pageDescription` somewhere, but there isn't a field called `pageDescription` setup for that particular entry.

Comment: Sweet!  Would you mind marking this as the answer?