# RSS throwing 404 error

Tags: error, 404, rss, feed

I used [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/any-working-rss-feed-examples-out-there) example to create an RSS feed in Craft, saved it as “feed.rss”, uploaded it into the “craft/templates” directory. When I go to www.my-website.com/rss, I get a 404.

What am I missing here? Any help is highly appretiated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have named the file `feed.rss`, and you are trying to access it by going to `/rss`. So I can see two issues here:

- The template file needs to be either `.html` or `.twig`, as per the
  tutorial you have referenced
- The name of the template file will dictate the URL for that template. If you re-name your template file to `feed.twig`, you access that template by going to `/feed`